# Display articles from database in bootstrap columns

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates

I have a large database of articles, I want to display them all in bootstrap `rows`(3 articles per row):

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-4 mb-4 text-center display-4">All News </h1>
    <div class="row">
        {% for article in articles %}
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="card">
                    <h2 class="pt-2"><a href="#">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="lead"> {{ article.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
    {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that `row` is created outside the `for` statement, so every article is squeezed into one `row` (when there should be 3 articles per `row`). Is there a way to loop through the `for` statement, and put 3 articles in one `row`, close that `row` and then begin a new one?

Comment: Is this bootstrap4?  In bootstap 3 you would do `<div class="col-md-4">` and on md and larger sized screens 4 of 12 columns would be taken.  I think you can do the same in bootstrap 4

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the value of `forloop.counter` to change the behavior every three iterations.

```
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="mt-4 mb-4 text-center display-4">All News </h1>
    <div class="row">
        {% for article in articles %}
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                <div class="row">
            {% endif %}
            <div class="col-md">
                <div class="card">
                    <h2 class="pt-2"><a href="#">{{ article.title }}</a></h2>
                    <p class="lead"> {{ article.description }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:3 %}
                </div>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```